# CURL command in Alamofire with swift

Tags: swift, curl, alamofire

I have the following working curl command which I need to run in Swift using Alamofire.

```
curl -k -i -d '{ "user": {"displayName":"My Test" ,"email":"test@xxtest.com","pwd":"test","roles":["stu"]}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8" -u web:web -X POST 'https://test.herokuapp.com/xtest/auth/register'
```

I tried out the following method with Swift by using Alamofire. I have the impression that I do -u web:web wrong, but I have no means to confirm that. 
The console gives me the following error which I don't understand:

```
print response object
  nil
print error
  Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.})
```

Can someone point out what is wrong in here? Thx.

This is the function which translates the CURL command into Swift

```
func registerNewStudent(displayName: String, email: String, password: String, completionHandler: (AnyObject?, NSError?) -> ()) {

//Basic HTTP auth
    let user = "web"
    let password = "web"

    let credentialData = "\(user):\(password)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])

    let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)"]

//example for a nested array query
  let parameters = [
        "user": [
            "displayName": displayName,
            "email": email,
            "pwd": password,
            "roles":["stu"]
        ]
    ]

    Alamofire.request(
        .POST,
        registerURL,
        headers: headers,
        parameters: parameters
        )
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success(let value):
                completionHandler(value, nil)
            case .Failure(let error):
                completionHandler(nil, error)
            }
    }
}
```

I call this function in the following way:

```
func okButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

   let displayNameText = displayNameInput.text
    let emailText = emailInput.text
    let passwordText = passwordInput.text

    restApi.registerNewStudent(displayNameText!,emailInput: emailText!, passwordInput: passwordText!) {responseObject, error in
        // use responseObject and error here

        print("print response object")
        print(responseObject)
        print("print error")
        print(error)
    }
```

Response from the CURL call:

```
{"result":{"email":"trrrrrest@xxtest.com","display_name":"My Test","pwd":"test","fb_id":null,"roles":["stu"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve it from here: http://www.ceus-now.com/curl-d-to-alamofire/

Adding the following line after the JSON response did the trick (not before).

```
    .authenticate(user: "web", password: "web")
```

so the method looks like:

```
  Alamofire.request(
        .POST,
        registerURL,
        parameters: parameters
        )
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success(let value):
                completionHandler(value, nil)
            case .Failure(let error):
                completionHandler(nil, error)
            }
    }
    .authenticate(user: "web", password: "web")
}
```